# "... help you get oriented for ..." or "... help get you oriented for ..."?

Tags: grammar

> We will look at just a few key things to ***help get you oriented for*** the recipes discussed in this chapter.

or

> We will look at just a few key things to ***help you get oriented for*** the recipes discussed in this chapter.

?

Answer (score 4):

Either one works.

> We will look at just a few key things
>   to help get you oriented for the
>   recipes discussed in this chapter.

This puts the emphasis on the speaker's group as the agents of the orientation process.

> We will look at just a few key things
>   to help you get oriented for the
>   recipes discussed in this chapter.

This implies that you will be doing most of the work, and "we" are here more as guides.